# Investigate convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Investigate convergence of the series:
$$\left( \frac{n^2+3n+10}{n^2+5n+17} \right)^{n^2 (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})}$$

It should be solvable with simple manipulations with the formula, i guess, but how to do that?

Comment: Is that formatted correctly, with the $n^2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})$ term as the exponent with base 10?

Comment: my mistake, the whole fraction is

Comment: Ouch... with a complex expression in the exponent like that, I don't know if the manipulations can stay simple. I'll take a longer look at it. Also, what do you mean by "the formula"?

Comment: the whole expression

Comment: @kurkowski: are you asking about convergence of the sequence whose term is given above, or of the series whose term is given above (the sum of the terms above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}=\frac2{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}
$$
and by cross-multiplication, for $n\ge20$,
$$
\frac{n^2+3n+10}{n^2+5n+17}\le\frac{n}{n+2}
$$
Therefore, using Bernoulli's Inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n^2+3n+10}{n^2+5n+17}\right)^{n^2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})}
&\le\left(\frac1{1+\frac2n}\right)^{n^2/\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&\le\frac1{1+\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n+1}}}\\[4pt]
&\to0
\end{align}
$$

---

Upon reading the question again, I am not certain whether you were wanting to know whether the terms above converge or whether their sum converges. Using the inequality
$$
1+x\le e^x
$$
we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n^2+3n+10}{n^2+5n+17}\right)^{n^2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1})}
&\le\left(1-\frac2{n+2}\right)^{n^2/\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&\le e^{-\frac{2n^2}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1}}}\\[9pt]
&\le e^{-2\sqrt{n-5}}
\end{align}
$$
since $\frac{2n^2}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1}}\ge2\sqrt{n-5}$. Thus, this term decays faster than any power of $n$. Therefore, even the sum converges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be the above term.  Note first that

$$\frac{n^2+3 n+10}{n^2+5 n+17} = \left (1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{10}{n^2} \right ) \left (1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{17}{n^2} \right )^{-1} = 1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+O\left (\frac1{n^3}\right )$$

Also,

$$n^2 \left ( \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}\right ) = n^{3/2} \left (1+\frac{3}{8 n^2} + O\left (\frac1{n^3}\right )\right ) $$

Then

$$\begin{align}\log{a_n} &= n^2 \left ( \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}\right ) \log{ \left [  1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+O\left (\frac1{n^3}\right )\right]} \\ &= n^{3/2} \left (1+\frac{3}{8 n^2} + O\left (\frac1{n^3}\right )\right ) \left (-\frac{2}{n} + \frac1{n^2} +  O\left (\frac1{n^3}\right ) \right )\\ &= -2 \sqrt{n} + \frac1{\sqrt{n}} + O \left ( n^{-3/2} \right ) \end{align}$$

which means that the general term in the series behaves as

$$e^{-2 \sqrt{n}} \left ( 1+ \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \right ) $$

for large $n$.  Thus the series converges.